# What is better way to join in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to join 3 or more tables

table1 - 1 thousand record

table2 - 100 thousands record

table3 - 10 millions record

Which of the following is best(speed wise performance):-

*Note: pk and fk are primary and foreign key for respective tables and FILTER_CONDITION1 and FILTER_CONDITION2 are respective restricting records query normally found in where*

**Case 1** *:taking smaller tables first and joining larger one later*

```
Select table1.*,table2.*,table3.* 
from table1 
join table2 
on table1.fk = table2.pk and FILTER_CONDITION1
join table3 
on table2.fk = table3.pk and FILTER_CONDITION2
```

**Case 2**

```
Select table1.*,table2.*,table3.* 
from table3 
join table2 
on table2.fk = table3.pk and FILTER_CONDITION2
join table1 
on table1.fk = table2.pk and FILTER_CONDITION1
```

**Case 3**

```
Select table1.*,table2.*,table3.* 
from table3 
join table2 
on table2.fk = table3.pk
join table1 
on table1.fk = table2.pk
where FILTER_CONDITION1 and FILTER_CONDITION2
```

Comment: In the same way that 1x2x3 = 3x2x1, these are all exactly equivalent, both in terms of performance and result.

Comment: perhaps not @Strawberry its more complex then 1x2x3 = 3x2x1 due to filter option which might reduce number of records for join.

Comment: No it isn't. That's where indexes come in.

Answer (score 2):

The cases you show are equivalent. What you are describing is in the end the same query and will be seen by the database as such: the database will make a query plan.

The best thing you can do is use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and check out what your query actually does: this way you can see they will probably be run the same, AND if there might be a bottle neck in there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nanne updated in his answer that normally mysql do it its own (right ordering) but some time (rare case) mysql can read table join in wrong order and can kill query performance in this case you can follow below approach-

If you can filter data from your bulky tables like table2 and table3 (suppose you can get only 500 records after joining these tables and applying filter) then first you filter your data and then you can join that filtered data with your small table..in this way you can get performance but there can be various combinations, so you have to check by which join you can do more filteration..yes explain will help you to know it and index will help you to get filtered data.

After above approach you can say mysql to use ordering as you have in your query by syntax "SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN....." same as some time mysql does not use proper index and we have to use force index

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by filter, but the database does this for you. It makes a plan what to 'filter' first so it will get you your data quickest. You answer seems to imply you need to do something yourself to get this in the right order. This is incorrect as far as this simple example is concerned. In some cases you might need to nudge it a bit, but you can't simply do that with re-ordering your joins.

Comment: @Nanne you are correct as normally mysql do it its own (right ordering) but some time (rare case) mysql can read table join in wrong order and can kill query performance in this case you can follow above approach with syntax "SELECT  STRAIGHT_JOIN....." same as some time mysql does not use proper index and we have to use force index...